# Scraping text between two span elements using Beautifulsoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was scraping a site using Beautifulsoup, and found text between 2 span elements (not between opening and closing tags).

How can I scrap the text between two span elements, such as:

```
<span class="description_start"></span> 
Text which I need to scrape
<span class="description_end"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to find first `<span>` and then `.find_next(text=True)`:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """\
<span class="description_start"></span> 
Text which I need to scrape
<span class="description_end"></span>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

t = soup.find("span", class_="description_start").find_next(text=True)
print(t)
```

Prints:

```
 
Text which I need to scrape
```